# How to change font size of a attributed string in a webview?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, nsattributedstring, mathml

The scenario is: For a chat app where two device can send text and image messages to each other and the recieved text in each device is an html which is rendered in a uiwebview. I was appending this string (header) to the received html

```
let header2 = "<html><head><style> img{max-width:100%; height:auto;
 object-fit: contain} table, td, tr, th { border: 1px solid; border-collapse: collapse;
 padding-left: 2px; fontface: FaktPro-Normal; color: #252949; line-height:20px }
 p, li, ol{line-height:24px;} </style><font face=\"FaktPro-Normal\" size=\"3.9\"
 color=\"#252949\"><script type=\"text/javascript\" 
src=\"http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML\"></script><script type=\"text/x-mathjax-config\">
\nMathJax.Hub.Config({\t \"messageStyle:\"none\",\"tex2jax:{preview:\"none\"},
\" \"HTML-CSS\": { scale: 90,minScaleAdjust:90,undefinedFamily: \" Amiri-Regular \",
showMathMenu : false },MatchWebFonts:
{matchFor:{\"HTML-CSS\":true,NativeMML :false}, fontCheckDelay: 2000, fontCheckTimeout: 30*1000} })</script></head><body>"
```

for changing the font and font size to a custom font. However, when the other device send attributed string instead of a string, this doesnt' works

Comment: If you are rendered on a uiwebview, you need HTML string so convert the attributed string to HTML string and process further as you are doing above.

Comment: Or you can render on UILable by converting the HTML string to attributed string. So your UILable will work for both.